# MariaDB: Optimum Way to Update Billions of Records

Tags: mysql, database, timestamp, mariadb

I am looking for an optimum way to update billions of records present in one table (Example below Table 3). Each entry is associated with a timestamp that is in the order of milliseconds. In this example Table 3 is out of date, Tables 1 and 2 are up to date with the real entries of their respective data. I do not have anything that links tables 1 and 2 to table 3. If needed, please also let me know as I am not a database expert.

Table 1 has 4 columns:

```
Timestamp T_0 PRIMARY KEY (ex: '2014-07-04 16:17:16.800000')
X1_T1 VARCHAR
X2_T1 VARCHAR
X3_T1 VARCHAR
```

Table 2 has 4 columns:

```
Timestamp T_0 PRIMARY KEY (ex: '2014-07-04 16:17:16.800000')
X1_T2 VARCHAR
X2_T2 VARCHAR
X3_T3 VARCHAR
```

Table 3 has 7 columns:

```
Timestamp T_0 PRIMARY KEY (ex: '2014-07-04 16:17:16.800000')
X1_T1 VARCHAR
X2_T1 VARCHAR
X3_T1 VARCHAR
X1_T2 VARCHAR
X2_T2 VARCHAR
X3_T3 VARCHAR
```

I was successful at updating table 3 using a procedure that loops through timestamps and updates each row using the command:

```
SET tmp_T_0=(SELECT '2014-01-05 17:00:00.000000'); // set to the start of the table's timestamp
label1: LOOP
  UPDATE TABLE3 SET
      X1_T1=(select X1_T1 FROM TABLE1 where T_0 = tmp_T_0),
      X2_T1=(select X2_T1 FROM TABLE1 where T_0 = tmp_T_0),
      X3_T1=(select X3_T1 FROM TABLE1 where T_0 = tmp_T_0),
      X1_T2=(select X1_T2 FROM TABLE2 where T_0 = tmp_T_0),
      X2_T2=(select X2_T2 FROM TABLE2 where T_0 = tmp_T_0),
      X3_T2=(select X3_T2 FROM TABLE2 where T_0 = tmp_T_0)
 WHERE T_0 = tmp_T_0;  

 SET tmp_T_0=(SELECT TIMESTAMP(tmp_T_0,'00:00:00.001')); //ADD one millisecond and continue

 SET LoopInt=(SELECT(LoopInt + 1));
 IF LoopInt < LoopEnd THEN
   ITERATE label1;
 END IF;
 LEAVE label1;
END LOOP label1;
```

The above method takes around 53 seconds for 100,000 entries. That is not acceptable because it would require around 100 days to complete the rest of entries.

It should be noted that it's not a must that Table 3 has data from tables 1 and/or 2 for each of its respective timestamp entries (i.e., a timestamp in Table 3 may contain data for X1_T1 X2_T1 and X3_T1 while the other values X1_T2 X2_T2 and X3_T2 is NULL).

Any suggestions would help.
Thank you

Comment: the above method is also running 9 separate sub-queries for each parent query... ugh

Comment: This is going to be a long-running job no matter what you do. Can you say more about the indexing data? Is there a row for every millisecond in your `TABLE3`?

Comment: Thanks for your input and yes there is a row for every millisecond in Table 3, but not in tables 1 and 2 where data is not as frequent. It is 6 months of data. 120 Billion rows/records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about trying this query to pull one hour's worth of info from TABLE1 to TABLE3?

```
UPDATE TABLE3 AS t3
  JOIN TABLE1 AS t1 ON t3.T_0 = t1.T_0
   SET t3.X1_T1 = IFNULL(t1.X1_T1,t3.X1_T1),
       t3.X2_T1 = IFNULL(t1.X2_T1,t3.X2_T1),
       t3.X3_T1 = IFNULL(t1.X3_T1,t3.X3_T1)
 WHERE t3.T_0 >= '2014-01-05' + INTERVAL 0 HOUR
   AND t3.T_0 <  '2014-01-05' + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
```

What's going on?  First, the `WHERE` clause limits the query's scope to one hour. That's handy because you can test stuff.  Also, you're going to want to loop this job hour by hour so your queries don't run for too long. If you're using InnoDB or Aria as a storage engine, if you don't limit the scope of your queries you'll blow out the transaction rollback space too.

You can run this query many times, each time with a change to the HOUR interval, like so.

```
 WHERE t3.T_0 >= '2014-01-05' + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
   AND t3.T_0 <  '2014-01-05' + INTERVAL 2 HOUR
```

You're JOINing TABLE1 to TABLE3. That's valid because you've said TABLE3 contains every possible timestamp, and TABLE1 doesn't. The way I have written this query, it won't touch the rows of TABLE3 that don't have corresponding rows in TABLE1. I think that's what you want.

Finally, the IFNULL() function arranges only to change the TABLE3 data when there's non-NULL TABLE1 data.

Look, if your TABLE1 data is sparse (that is, it has lots of randomly scattered valid values in a table that is mostly NULL) you probably want to use three queries like this instead, so you don't actually change rows in TABLE3 unless you have new data. Changing values in rows is relatively expensive.

```
UPDATE TABLE3 AS t3
  JOIN TABLE1 AS t1 ON t3.T_0 = t1.T_0
   SET t3.X1_T1 = t1.X1_T1
 WHERE t3.T_0 >= '2014-01-05' + INTERVAL 0 HOUR
   AND t3.T_0 <  '2014-01-05' + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
   AND t1.X1_T1 IS NOT NULL

UPDATE TABLE3 AS t3
  JOIN TABLE1 AS t1 ON t3.T_0 = t1.T_0
   SET t3.X2_T1 = t1.X2_T1
 WHERE t3.T_0 >= '2014-01-05' + INTERVAL 0 HOUR
   AND t3.T_0 <  '2014-01-05' + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
   AND t1.X2_T1 IS NOT NULL

UPDATE TABLE3 AS t3
  JOIN TABLE1 AS t1 ON t3.T_0 = t1.T_0
   SET t3.X3_T1 = t1.X3_T1
 WHERE t3.T_0 >= '2014-01-05' + INTERVAL 0 HOUR
   AND t3.T_0 <  '2014-01-05' + INTERVAL 1 HOUR
   AND t1.X3_T1 IS NOT NULL
```

You will need to repeat all this for your TABLE2 data.

You may want to run this whole thing in a single query. Don't do that! This is the kind of job you need to be able to do an hour at a time and restart when needed. I suggest an hour at a time, but that is 3.6 megarows.  You might want to do even smaller chunks at a time, like 6 minutes (360 kilorows).

If I were you I'd definitely debug this whole deal on a copy of a couple of days' worth of your TABLE3.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion above. I will try it out and re-post the estimated time needed to have all records updated using your approach by using couple of days worth of data as you suggested.

Comment: That was an awesome approach. Thank you, I did apply it and it saved a lot of time to execute. In total, it took (15 hours 11 min 20.96 sec) to update the whole table TABLE3. I applied the one-hour approach (3.6 megarows).

However, when I ran the the trial simulation on a 'one day' worth of data (i.e., 24 hour loop with i = 1 to 24), it took 15 seconds to join both tables into TABLE3. When I increased the loop to 6 months of data (i.e, i = 1 to 4320), it took 15 hours when it should have taken 45 minutes only based on the estimated simulation of 24 hours. I did something wrong didn't I?

Comment: That was faster than I thought. That's great! I suspect your 15 hour run was nonlinearly larger than your smaller runs because you ran out of RAM in the server for some bunch of temp data and it had to flush it to the hard drive. Now, what are you going to do with the next 99 days and nine hours?  :-)

Comment: DOUBLE CHECK THAT YOUR RESULTS ARE RIGHT!  But you knew that.

Comment: Thanks again, results are correct. I double checked them.
I have much more to do :-)